# Frame work accessibility issue in swift project

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on swift frameworks and created two frame works formework-A and framework-B,

formework-B imports the framework-A.

and when import fromwork-B in my project i am unable to access the classes in framework-A.

can any one help how to solve this access issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the framework's files must be inside the project. Sometimes, you might have to change the position of the files inside of the object tree pane.

You might also have to clean the project (Command + shift + K)/quit Xcode.

Comment: framework-A already contained framework-B, but why the both framework's files must be inside the project ? it is duplication and increase the project size right ?

Comment: But when you call import, Xcode searches the project directory for a framework that doesn't exist within it. For example, if you were to ship the app, how would the app access framework-A if the files aren't inside the project.